# Javascript : Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I have a function in a JS file that allows me to perform a select on a Web SQL database of my browser.
When I display my page the browser console tells me that the function does not exist. I confess I do not understand
because she is present there. I have other functions that I use in this same file and that works correctly. the error i get :

```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: getUser is not defined
at affichage_web_sql.html:20
(anonymous) @ affichage_web_sql.html:20***
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Affichage données base Web SQL.</title>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/sql.js">
        </script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/dom.js">
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            EcrireHeader("Lecture des données Web SQL.");
            EcrireMenu();
        </script>

        <main>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                try
                {
                    getUser();
                }
                catch(err)
                {
                    alert(err.message);
                }
                /*try
                {
                    window.onload = function()
                    {
                        var db = openDatabase(dbName, version, dbDisplayName, dbSize);
                        db.transaction(function(e)
                        {
                            e.executeSql("SELECT * FROM User",[],function(e,results)
                            {
                                var nbRec = results.rows.length;
                                var i,usr;
                                for (i=0;i<nbRec;i++)
                                {
                                    usr = results.rows.item(i);
                                    alert(usr.Nom + " " + usr.prenom);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
                catch(err)
                {
                    alert(err.message)
                }*/
            </script>
        </main>

        <script  type="text/javascript">
            EcrireFooter();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here JS file :

```
var version = 1.0;
var dbName = "mydb";
var dbDisplayName = "mydb";
var dbSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
/*Si la base n'existe pas, celle-ci est créée et la connexion ouverte et créé les tables si elles n'existent pas dans la base.
Sinon, ouvre simplement la connexion à la base.*/       
function InitialiseBase()
{
    var db;

    try 
    {
        db = openDatabase(dbName, version, dbDisplayName, dbSize, function(database) 
            {
                alert("database creation callback");
            });

            db.transaction(function(t)
            {
                /* Place SQL statements here */
                t.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(Nom varchar(50), prenom varchar(50))", [], function(sqlTransaction, sqlResultSet) 
                {

                }, function(sqlTransaction, sqlError) 
                {
                    alert(sqlError.message)
                });
            }, function() 
                {
                    alert("SQL statements were executed successfully.");
                });
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err.message)
    }
}

function onSuccess(e) { }
function onError(e) { }

function insertData(nom, prenom) 
{
    var db = openDatabase(dbName, version, dbDisplayName, dbSize);
    db.transaction(function (e) 
    {
        e.executeSql("INSERT INTO User(Nom, Prenom) VALUES (?, ?)", [nom, prenom]);//, onSuccess, onError);
    });
}

function deleteUser(id)
{
    try
    {
        var db = openDatabase(dbName, version, dbDisplayName, dbSize);
        db.transaction(function (e) 
        {
            e.executeSql("DELETE FROM User WHERE rowid = ?", [id]);//, onSuccess, onError);
        });
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err.message);
    }
}

function getUser()
{
    try
    {
        var nbRec,i,usr;
        var db = openDatabase(dbName, version, dbDisplayName, dbSize);
        db.transaction(function(e)
        {
            e.executeSql("SELECT * FROM User",[],function(e,results)
            {
                nbRec = results.rows.length;

                for (i=0;i<nbRec;i++)
                {
                    usr = results.rows.item(i);
                    alert(usr.Nom + " " + usr.prenom);
                }
            });
        });
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be no problem in the way your file is loaded in your HTML. Your problem probably lies somewhere else.

Comment: clean project, app server and what not.. import looks correct

Comment: i did but nothing change :(

Comment: If you open your console and let it show your http requests, do you get your js files properly?

Comment: Yes, I get the JS file properly.
i open dev tool then i go to network and i see my JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is probably poorly loaded, I tested your code, the function is well executed. You say that other functions work properly but they are in another JS file, check if your file is found.

Comment: I just do a little .NET program to check if my files (C:\Users\laubry_a\Desktop\test_html5\js\sql.js) exists and it exists. I confess that I don't understand this mistery.